# lp and c0 little question

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

i want to explain that the inclusion $\bigcup_{p < \infty} l^p \subset c_0$ is true. that comes very quickly from the definition of $l^p$. The problem is, that Im sure  that this inclusion is strict but I can't think on a counterexample. At this moment i think on something like $x_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt[p]{n} } $  but it doesn't seem to work. Any hint please?

Comment: $$x_n=\frac1{\log(n+3)}$$

Comment: @Did Thanks a lot!